# How can I "start a Fragment with an Intent"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

first of, I know that it is not possible to start a fragment via an Intent like you do with activities. However, in my application I would like to have the functionality that I can return from the activity to a fragment on a button click.

How do I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: updated the question. I meant "return from an activity to a fragment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "return from an Activity to a Fragment", simply because Fragments need to be put somewhere. Which means that hey need an Activity as a container. Putting aside some dirty overlay tricks.

So in the usual cases, you need an Activity to hold your Fragments. And since you have an Activity, you can have an `intent-filter` to handle your intent.

Comment: ok. in my intent in return to the activity that hosts the fragments. How do i then pick the according fragment?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I suggest going the startActivityForResult() pattern, rather than the Intent one.
Anyways, you can store stuff in an intentt the same way you would always do...

Answer (score 0):

Activity hosts fragment, I think you should return to an Activity and select the correct Fragment. But there's always problem if you wanna select a Fragment freely, because you might have had a Fragment-Stack. If you don't have, ignore what I wrote below.

You have maybe three chance to reach your points. If you've called addBackStack, by default the Android use a backstack to control your Fragments, you have no chance to select your Fragments freely. so....

Chance 1 maybe worse case: Do not use addBackStack, and always use replace to finish your fragment's transaction.

Chance 2: Use FragmentTabHost. Then you can free select your fragments you've created, but be care of their life-cycles.

Chance 3: Use ViewPager, u know it ! :)